# Select only leaf SPAN elements via XPath

Tags: java, html, xml, selenium, xpath

I am using Java and Selenium and testng on Windows 7.
My HTML code looks like this (this is just part):

```
<TR>
  <TH>
    <SPAN>Some Text 1</SPAN>
  </TH>
  <TH>
    <SPAN>
      <A id="someid" href="http://someurl">
        <SPAN> Some Text 2</SPAN>
      </A>
    </SPAN>
  </TH>
 </TR>
```

In other words "Some Text 1" and "Some Text 2" are at different levels of span.  I am trying to come up with an XPath to find them.  I can't use `*//TR//SPAN*` because that would get the additional `SPAN` above the "Some Text 2". I can't look for a `SPAN` with text because some of the ones I find will have no text.  What I believe I can assume is that the `SPAN` I am looking for will always be the lowest level `SPAN` under the TH.

So is there an XPath I can use?  I suppose instead of using an @FindBy I could do some sort of dynamic recursive loop to find a span and keep searching for spans underneath it until I come to a leaf, but that sounds kind of tricky.

Answer (score 3):

This XPath

```
//SPAN[not(*)]
```

will select all `SPAN` elements that have no children elements, so it'll select

```
<SPAN>Some Text 1</SPAN>
<SPAN>Some Text 2</SPAN>
```

but not the `SPAN` that contains the Text 2 `SPAN`, as requested.

If you want to restrict the `SPAN` element selected to only those leaf 'SPAN' elements that are somewhere under `TH` elements:

```
//TH//SPAN[not(*)]
```

Answer (score 1):

according to your question you want to find the `SPAN` elements that

- are below a `TH` element
- do not contain another `SPAN` element below them

you can try this xpath then:

```
String xpath = "//TH//SPAN[not(.//SPAN)]"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't do xpath but I can provide some css assistance.

```
$$("th span:last-of-type")
```

What this will do is identify (all) the last child spans of a 'th'.

Comment: Thanks.  I was off a couple days so I just saw this now.  I will try it.